# Text between 2 lines in Pinescript for Tradingview Chart

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading, tradingview-api, forex

I am currently developing a sessions indicator (as a trader I don't really know much about coding) with the name of the session in between 2 lines I was able to add the lines but now I am missing the text on the screen that will display "Asian", "New York", "London".

How do I get the text to always be between those 2 points and always happen?

```
//@version=5
indicator('Sessions With Name', overlay=true)
color_1 = color.rgb(0,0,0,85)

//Asian Session
a = input.session(title='Asian', defval='2000-2001')
a1 = time(timeframe.period, a)
bgcolor(a1 ? color_1 : na)

//London Session
l = input.session(title='London', defval='0300-0301')
l1 = time(timeframe.period, l)
bgcolor(l1 ? color_1 : na)

//New York Session
ny = input.session(title='New York', defval='0800-0801')
ny1 = time(timeframe.period, ny)
bgcolor(ny1 ? color_1 : na)
```

I tried using tables to write the text with the `table.cell` function and was able to display the text but It was fixed onto the screen, I was hoping it would be fixed in the middle of the two lines and always happen at that time.